# The 'plating material' materials and constants of the constants

Tags: impedance

The 'plating material' materials and constants of the [Single-Layer Helical Round Wire Coil Inductor Calculator](http://hamwaves.com/antennas/inductance.html) appear wired-in. 
There appears no 'un-plated' option.

How to use this calculator to work with un-plated magnet wire?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the calculator does not require an input for the material characteristics of the underlying wire but rather only the plating. This is a clear indication that the author expects the AC current to be fully contained within the skin material. This would be plausible given the [skin effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) of AC current.

You can select two forms of copper if your wire has no plating. Also note that the pull down material selector pre-populates the conductivity and permeability fields as a matter of convenience. You may manually populate these fields for other materials.

If you are using common solid copper wire, *annealed copper* would be a suitable choice.

The website is authored by Serge Stroobandt, ON4AA as indicated on the [homepage](http://www.hamwaves.com/index/en/index.html).